# Regex Ignore words with part of string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a text:

```
'1 2 3 ab AB úá awindow BCwindow'
```

Currently to get only words I use this regex: `[a-zA-Zá-ú]+` and this is the result:

```
['ab', 'awindow', 'bcwindow', 'úá']
```

I would like to remove 'window' string of mathes words to get this:

```
['ab','a','bc','úá']
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the rule here?

Comment: Iterate over array and replace window thing or try [`(?<!\S)[a-zA-Zá-ú]+?(?:(?!\S)|(?=window))`](https://regex101.com/r/8CYxAy/1) if *window* is supposed to come after all letters.

Comment: Also, try [`re.findall(r'\b(?:(?!window\b)[^\W\d_])+', s)`](https://ideone.com/r1lFsO)

Comment: @revo Answers works perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If word *window* always appears at the end of a matching word, you could do:

```
(?<!\S)[a-zA-Zá-ú]+?(?:(?!\S)|(?=window))
```

This assures you don't have extra non-whitespace characters preceding a word (prevents a match to begin from middle of a longer string) or following it. You may use word boundaries `\b` instead:

```
\b[a-zA-Zá-ú]+?(?:\b|(?=window))
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/lWB5Ay/1)

Breakdown:

- `\b` Match a word boundary position (where a word begins)
- `[a-zA-Zá-ú]+?` Match characters in class at least one time, ungreedily
- `(?:` Start of non-capturing group

  - `\b` Match a word boundary (here we mean end of word)
  - `|` Or
  - `(?=window)` A positive lookahead, assert following characters are `window`
- `)` End of non-capturing group

Whenever second word boundary is matched or positive lookahead asserts then engine is satisfied and every thing up to that point is returned as a match.

Comment: Can you please explain each one step by step? Thanks.